# If a language consists of an NP and coNP question, do we have to place it in P^NP^NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time-reductions

If $x \in L$ only if $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, where A is an NP problem and B is a coNP problem, I cannot place $L \in NP$ or $L \in coNP$ without implying that NP = coNP right?

Comment: Yes, there is a specific complexity class for this type of languages. I think it is called DP if I remember correctly.

Comment: Let $L=A=B$ and $L \in P$. Then $L = A \cap B$, $A \in NP$, $B \in coNP$, as required in the statement, and you don't need $NP=coNP$ for $L$.

Comment: The language $\Sigma^*$ is both in NP and in coNP. If we take $A=B=\Sigma^*$ then we get $L=\Sigma^*$, which is unconditionally both in NP and in coNP.

Answer (score 2):

No, because $A$ isn't necessarily $NP$-complete and $B$ isn't necessarily $coNP$-complete.  You'd need both to be true to force the implication $NP = coNP$ by $X$ being a member of both problem classes.  In fact $A$ and $B$ could both be in $NP$ **and** $coNP$.  E.g. $A$ and $B$ could both be in $P$.  $NP \cap coNP$ is not the empty set.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. So if they are both NP-complete/coNP-complete it would indeed imply that NP = coNP?

Comment: @Friedrich Yes.